# Font-size vary when responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsiveness

just got such a problem – I've got a lightbox program on my page to show pictures as a slideshow. Everything looks like it should on a wide screen (for example on the monitor) but when I watch it on my smartphone (also on its simulator in Google Chrome) it is always the various font-size at each picture! Here, for example: [One of examples where it's the case](http://schachnowskij-p.bplaced.net/referenzen/HMKOM.html). I've checked the CSS, everything must be OK, but it isn't. Can someone help me, maybe there's a bug in the JS program, or even in the CSS?

Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: Do you wonder why you see different style in mobile and desktop?

Comment: As I couldn't put in the js and the css code, here are links to the files: [css](http://schachnowskij-p.bplaced.net/css/lightbox.min.css) and  [js](http://schachnowskij-p.bplaced.net/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js)

Comment: But what are you asking?
Please be more specific: font-size of which text?

Comment: @AlonShmiel no, it's just the font-size that is different under different pictures in mobile. Font-size of the text under the picture in the lightbox.

Comment: for example: this one?
Zweite von drei Doppelseiten der Broschüre als Layoutbeispiel.

Comment: @AlonShmiel yes. It's smaller than the other ones (as "Erste von drei Doppelseiten der Broschüre als Layoutbeispiel. Die dritte Doppelseite wurde nach demselben Motiv gestaltet.")

Answer (score 1):

These is a css media query that you can control the styles in each screen sizes (by with and height).

For your example:

```
if you open the console.
Click on element tab.
search: .lb-caption
```

You will see that on mobile it has this media query:

```
@media (min-height: 1060px) and (min-width: 980px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

it's because someone want to add style when the query is true.

The font-size is: 150%.

If you change it to specific font-size (not based on percentages, it should be the same).

i.e. font-size: 30px;

Comment: thank you. However, I tried it, now the font sizes are in px, but the problem is still not solved – now the font under the third picture is normal and under the both first ones it's large :-O

Comment: hi, [it's the same one](http://schachnowskij-p.bplaced.net/referenzen/HMKOM.html)